# How to get the number of the key value pairs in a Kafka Streams InMemoryWindowStore

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

What is the most efficient way to get the number of the key value pairs (and the number of the windows if possible) in an InMemoryWindowStore? I would like to capture the number periodically for monitoring purposes.

The only way I can think of right now is to call the all() method and traverse everything in a punctuator. The problem with this is that it blocks the streaming process for a long time and I’m not sure if it can meet my throughput requirement. Another option might be using a separate thread but I’m not sure if it’s safe.

There seems to be no equivalent of approximateNumEntries() in the window store. Is there any API which allows capturing the same thing in a window store? Is it safe to do the traversal on the state store object from a separate thread?